# Sending pic via email without the use of intent

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent

Hi I would like to know is it possible not to invoke intent or use of Intent.createChooser when sending pics via email?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [JavaMail Api](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) to send the mail.

Refer this for [example](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent)